# How do I loop an array of objects and return it's value inside the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For some reason it's returning both the key and value an excessive number of times. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function loopAnArrayOfObjects(arrayOfObjects) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
      for (var key in arrayOfObjects) {
          console.log(arrayOfObjects[key]);
      }
  }
}

loopAnArrayOfObjects([{a: 1, b: 2}, {z: 5, y: 6}, {q: 14} ]);
// expected console output:
  // 1
  // 2
  // 5
  // 6
  // 14

loopAnArrayOfObjects([{queue: false, stack: true}, {fish: 'swims'}, {shirt: 's', pop: 'p', eye: 'e'} ]);
// expected console output:
  // false
  // true
  // swims
  // s
  // p
  // e
```

Comment: For the inner loop, did you mean `for (var key in arrayOfObjects[i]) { console.log(arrayOfObjects[i][key]);`?

Comment: Is the expected out or the actual output in the comments?

Comment: I'll put this as a comment, but you can use `.reduce()` to remove the counters too: `[{a: 1, b: 2}, {z: 5, y: 6}, {q: 14} ].reduce((acc,next)=>{for(key in next) acc.push(next[key]); return acc;},[])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each iteration, the current element/object is `arrayOfObjects[i]`, which is what you should be using.

```js
function loopAnArrayOfObjects(arrayOfObjects) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
      for (var key in arrayOfObjects[i]) {
          console.log(arrayOfObjects[i][key]);
      }
  }
}
loopAnArrayOfObjects([{queue: false, stack: true}, {fish: 'swims'}, {shirt: 's', pop: 'p', eye: 'e'} ]);
```

Alternatively, you can use `for ... of` to loop over just the elements without the index.

```js
function loopAnArrayOfObjects(arrayOfObjects) {
  for(const obj of arrayOfObjects){
      for (const key in obj) {
          console.log(obj[key]);
      }
  }
}
loopAnArrayOfObjects([{queue: false, stack: true}, {fish: 'swims'}, {shirt: 's', pop: 'p', eye: 'e'} ]);
```

Comment: This answer actually answers the question "_What did I do wrong._"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looping over arrays, it's best these days to do it with one of the `Array.prototype` methods. [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a great replacement for traditional counting loops because it does away with the need to set up and manage a counter and instead gives you direct access to the elements within the array.  This simplification can often remove closures that will often cause problems or just make it easier to understand what you are working with. Then, when needing to loop over the object keys, you can use a [for/in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to also make it much simpler.

```js
loopAnArrayOfObjects([{a: 1, b: 2}, {z: 5, y: 6}, {q: 14} ]);
// console output:
  // 1
  // 2
  // 5
  // 6
  // 14

loopAnArrayOfObjects([{queue: false, stack: true}, {fish: 'swims'}, {shirt: 's', pop: 'p', eye: 'e'} ]);
// console output:
  // false
  // true
  // swims
  // s
  // p
  // e
  
function loopAnArrayOfObjects(ary){
  ary.forEach(function(arrayItem){
    // This will be the objects in the array
    // Now, set up a secondary loop to go over the keys in the object
    for(key in arrayItem){
      console.log(arrayItem[key]);
    }
  });
}
```